# IMFResponse responseWithWLResponse unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: xcode, swift, ibm-cloud, ios9.2, ibm-mobile-services

[Similar to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987182/ios-application-crashes-when-trying-to-register-the-device-to-ibm-mobile-first-p).

Below is a snippet from the console.

```
Timestamp App Name[315:36110] [INFO] [IMFPushClient] -[IMFPushClient registerDeviceToken:completionHandler:] in IMFPushClient.m:70 :: Verifying previous device registration.
IMFAuthorizationManager.m:453 :: There is no cached authorization header, use obtainAuthorizationHeaderWithCompletionHandler to get the header
Timestamp App Name[315:36110] +[IMFResponse responseWithWLResponse:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100101c30
```

1. Did not use cocoapod to install IMFCore framework. Reference framework directly.
2. Added -Objc flag in linker->other linker flags for Project and target.
3. Problem detected when debugging on iPhone 6+ iOS version 9.2.1.
4. Cannot recreate issue with Xcode iPhone 6+ simulator iOS version 9.2.

Would appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on my problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Can you write down the error/problem while debugging iPhone 6+ iOS version 9.2.1.

Comment: One thing to note is you cannot do push notification registration on a simulator so it would make sense it was not reproducible there. Please provide the code you are using for registration

Comment: @Jaalger thank you for pointing that out. I will try to trigger the IMFPushClient.sharedInstance().registerDeviceToken function programmatically to see if if the problem can be replicated in the simulator.

Comment: @MihribanMinaz I am trying to register my app to receive remote notification from APNS using Bluemix's IMFPush framework.
The IMFPushClient.sharedInstance().registerDeviceToken is called in the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate function. I hit unrecoginzed selector error even with -Objc linker flag set.

Comment: I've triggered the IMFPushClient.sharedInstance().registerDeviceToken function programmatically using the simulator. I hit the unrecognized selector error even in the iOS 9.2 simulator.

Comment: Hi All. Thank you for you feedbacks. Problem solved. Problem was with the other linker flag value. Entered -Obj*c* instead of -Obj*C*

Answer (score 0):

As Jason pointed out in his latest comment, please make sure the -ObjC flag under **Build Settings>Linking>Other Linker Flags** is entered correctly. This value is case sensitive so make sure the O and C are capitalized correctly:

-ObjC