# Unable to run bms-samples-cordova-hellopush - bms_samples_cordova_push-Swift.h file not found

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to run the Push notifications sample available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush). 
Unfortunately, the configuration as outlined [here](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/#configuration) doesn't work.

Docs say:
At the top of your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "[your-project-name]-Swift.h"
```

If your project name has spaces or hyphens, replace them with underscores in the import statement.

Example:

```
// Project name is "Test Project" or "Test-Project"
#import "Test_Project-Swift.h"
```

So I did for the sample:

```
#import "bms_samples_cordova_push-Swift.h"
```

ObjC Bridging Header is set to:

`bms-samples-cordova-push/Plugins/ibm-mfp-core/Bridging-Header.h`

Runpath is set to:

`@executable_path/Frameworks`

But Xcode throws the error above. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the `bms-samples-cordova-hellopush` sample application running using the following steps:

1. Cloned the sample:

   `git clone https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush`
2. Added my **APPLICATION_ROUTE** and **APPLICATION_GUID** in my `[your-directory]/www/js/index.js` (after configuring Push Notifications for my Mobile Services Starter application on Bluemix
3. Added the iOS platform to my application:

   `cordova platform add ios@3.9`
4. Added the Cordova plugin:

   `cordova plugin add ibm-mfp-push`
5. Opened my `[your-app-name].xcodeproj` file in my `[your-app-name]/platforms/ios` directory with Xcode (when I was prompted: **Convert to Latest Swift Syntax**, I clicked **Cancel**)
6. Added the Bridging Header. Went to `Build settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging Header` and added the following path:

   `[your-project-name]/Plugins/ibm-mfp-core/Bridging-Header.h`

[image: bridging header]

7. Add the Frameworks parameter. Went to `Build Settings > Linking > Runpath Search Paths` and added the following parameter:

   `@executable_path/Frameworks`

[image: executable path]

8. Built Project
9. Uncommented the following Push import statements in my bridging header. Went to `[your-project-name]/Plugins/ibm-mfp-core/Bridging-Header.h`:

[image: bridging header]

10. Updated my client application to use the Push SDK

Here is my updated `AppDelegate.m`:

```
/*
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
 */

//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  bms-samples-cordova-push
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "bms_samples_cordova_push-Swift.h"


#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, viewController;

- (id)init
{
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

    int cacheSizeMemory = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32 * 1024 * 1024; // 32MB
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
#else
        NSURLCache* sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
#endif
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate implementation

/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    [[CDVMFPPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunch:launchOptions];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if bms-samples-cordova-push-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (!url) {
        return NO;
    }

    // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

    return YES;
}

// repost all remote and local notification using the default NSNotificationCenter so multiple plugins may respond
- (void)            application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification
{
    // re-post ( broadcast )
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVLocalNotification object:notification];
}


#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
#endif
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide what's allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}

// Register device token with Bluemix Push Notification Service
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    
    [[CDVMFPPush sharedInstance] didRegisterForRemoteNotifications:deviceToken];
}

// Handle error when failed to register device token with APNs
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    
    [[CDVMFPPush sharedInstance] didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications:error];
}

// Handle receiving a remote notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    
    [[CDVMFPPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}

@end
```

10. Ran the sample on an iOS device to actually register and receive Push Notifications

Hopefully I didn't miss anything :0)

I've contacted and opened up a few issues with the Cordova team to improve the quality of this sample to make it easier to set up.

**Edit:** Also, as noted from Sebastian below, you need to disable bitcode.

Comment: If I followed these steps exactly on order, it worked. In addition, I had to disable bitcode and create a new instance of the push service because it was throwing HTTP 500 errors. Thanks a lot